# Use of "впору" when it doesn't mean "to fit just right"

Tags: словоупотребление, наречия

It seems that впору has another idiomatic meaning, aside from "fitting just right," as seen in this example:

> “Речь профессора Стебль была едва слышна — дождь барабанил по крыше
>   теплицы так, что граду **впору** позавидовать.”

And in this one:

> “Невилл, брось обертку в урну, она тебе их столько надавала, что **впору**
>   уже комнату обклеивать.”

Could someone please explain this usage and perhaps give me a few more examples in plain language? Also, is this literary or colloquial?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Means something like "**might just as well**". I would describe it as "flowery language": not exactly "colloquial" in the usual sense (often spoken in the streets) but not official too. More expected of literature or some mildly informal speech/article/interview etc.

- "Тут впору сделать заметку на полях." ~ "And now one could very well make a marginal note"
- "Теперь лицо ее просияло так, что впору было зажмуриться." ~ "Now her face was lit up to such an extent you might as well close your eyes"

Used to express the idea that something happened/happens so intensively or pronounced that you have only one thing left to do or it is the most obvious thing to do.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! However, I'm having trouble relating your explanation and examples to the two sentences I posted. Could you translate/paraphrase them for me?

Comment: Example 1: rain pattered so recklessly that hail might have felt ashamed.

Comment: Example 2: so much wrapping that one might use it to paper all the room with it.

Comment: You can think of it as a metaphorical extension based on the word "пора": as if the situation was so "strong" that "it might be the right time to do something or even past the point". Of course, not literally. Just to exaggerate how expressed some quality/problem is.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I didn't even realize that was the same root -пор-. Thanks again :)

Comment: I might be wrong but I think that the word `впору` is a bit deprecated or at least it is a literary. I do not think that this word is much used in common talks.